# Need to trim a string till end after a particular combination of characters

Tags: c#, string, trim

I need help in trimming everything in my string till end after it encounters the first "\0"

So:

**"test\1\2\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0_asdfgh_qwerty_blah_blah_blah"**

becomes

**"test\1\2\3"**

I am using c#. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try a regular expression replacement: `s/^([^\0]+)\0.*/$1/` should work. Unfortunately I don't know my C# well enough to type it out without looking it up.

Comment: Is that an escaped `(char)0` or the literal string `"\0"`?

Comment: Matt: I will try out your regex replacement. Thanks.

Comment: Ryan: It was supposed to be an escape char. But its a literal string. Why its so? Because I am getting this string from a win32 API (which I am calling as an extern in c#). Somehow this whole mechanism of calling c functions in c# doesn't work extremely well, so it gives me back  string which is terminated by sequence of "\0" instead of null char '\0'.

Comment: Everyone: Thanks for your solutions, I will try out and see what suits me best  and let you all know what I used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
string s = "test\1\2\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0_asdfgh_qwerty_blah_blah_blah";

int offset = s.IndexOf("\\0");
if (offset >= 0)
    s = s.Substring(0, offset);
```

Comment: What if input string doesn't contain such substring? It will throw an Exception

Comment: s = s.Substring(0, Math.Max(0,s.IndexOf("\\0"));

Comment: That's incorrect too, since the second argument to `Substring` is the length.  You'd want `Math.Max(s.Length, s.IndexOf("\\0")`.

Comment: @abatishchev: more than he asked for, but sure.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (someString.Contains("\\0"))
    someString = someString.Substring(0, someString.IndexOf("\\0"));
```

Comment: What would happen if you didn't have "if" in there? would you get the same string back that you were searching????

Comment: @VoodooChild: `IndexOf` will return -1 if original string doesn't contain substring and this will break `Substring`

Comment: @Anthony: Also you can use `(@"\0")` to make code more readable

Comment: @abatishchev, I'm aware, but someone else may not be. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Find the position of the first occurrence of "\0" and make another string which is a substring of you original from start to the position of the first occurrence.

Comment: I better get an up vote for the thoughtful explanation instead of just throwing the answer up on the board lol....

Answer (score 1):

`somestring=Regex.split(somestring,"\\0")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Substring(0, String.IndexOf("\0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (origString.IndexOf(@"\0") != -1) {
   newString = origString.Substring(0, origString.IndexOf(@"\0");
} else {
    newString = origString;
}
```

Comment: I see I'm the only one who took into account the case where there is no `\0` in the string :)

Answer (score 0):

The match value returned by the following regex should be what you're after as well (as alternative to the substring method), basically it begins at the string start and as long as the next two characters aren't `\0` it expands the match:

```
^(?:(?!=\0).)+
```